# Is there a way to prevent calling the constructor without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, declaration

i.e. this should be ok:

```
Object obj("param");
```

but this should not:

```
Object("param");
```

Is there a way to prevent the second scenario from being done?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`nodiscard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute for a type (with C++17 or later).

```
struct [[nodiscard]] Object {};

auto main() -> int {
  Object{}; // error
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work : https://godbolt.org/z/jz4EYsaqT

Comment: Works for clang and MSVC, gcc ignores it - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Gs5Wrfqez . Update all 3 report the problem with the attribute on the constructor - live  - https://godbolt.org/z/b6on7h3xd

Comment: I'm surprised the question isn't getting more upvotes

Comment: @PaulSanders I was surprised that I couldn't find a similar question/answer on here, maybe I can rephrase the title or ask it in a better way?

Comment: Maybe "Can I ensure, when a constructor is called, that the result is assigned to a variable and not simply discarded".  Hmmm, not sure if that's an improvement.